# angularJS radio buttons not functioning

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, radio-button

I'm having trouble communicating with my angularJS radio buttons.  I'm using the material design framework.  I'm fairly new to angular.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <md-radio-group class="user-type">
        <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-between" layout-align-sm="space-around center">
            <md-radio-button ng-model="userType" value="prospective" name="user_type" ng-change='newValue(value)'>Prospective Patient</md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button ng-model="userType" value="patient" name="user_type" ng-change='newValue(value)'>Patient</md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button ng-model="userType" value="caregiver" name="user_type" ng-change='newValue(value)'> Caregiver </md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button ng-model="userType" value="doctor" name="user_type" ng-change='newValue(value)'>Doctor</md-radio-button>
        </div>
    </md-radio-group>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    };

    $scope.$watch('userType', function(value){
        if(value == "patient"){
            console.log(value);
            self.showPatientStepTwo = true;
        }else{
            console.log(value);
            self.showPatientStepTwo = false;
        }

    });
}])
```

My ng-change isn't firing and my $watch isn't working either.
Can anyone find where I'm going wrong?  I can't communicate between my controller and view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the controller as syntax, you should bind to that instead of the scope. I think the md-radio-button directive was creating a child scope that was messing things up but hard to reproduce without that directive.

Here's a plunker with the model and click bound to ctrl instead of $scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/fSTBDAMZLFKJgRD4br9K?p=preview

Radios changed to input, but referencing the ctrl:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.userType" value="prospective" name="user_type" class="user-type-rdo md-warn md-hue-2" ng-change='ctrl.newValue(value)'>Prospective Patient
```

And the controller updated to move the newValue function off $scope:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    this.newValue = function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    };

    $scope.$watch(function(){return self.userType;}, function(value){   
        if(value == "patient"){
            console.log(value);
            self.showPatientStepTwo = true;
        }else{
            console.log(value);
            self.showPatientStepTwo = false;
        }

    });
}])
```

The newValue function logs undefined - not sure what you were trying to do there, but you can use self.userType in the newValue function if you want the value.

Comment: I believe he is using angular-material in his use case rather that standard inputs. Also, doesn't hardcoding `ctrl.userType` in the watch prohibit later use of the same controller in a manner such as `ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm"`?

Comment: Good point...what's the right way to set up a watch when using controller as?

Comment: I really don't need $watch if I could get my ng-change directive to work, right?  I'm just trying to save userType!

Answer (score 1):

First thing: You don't need to declare an `ng-model` on ea. angular-material radio button when using radio groups, as per the [angular-material docs](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.radioButton) for radio buttons.

The second thing is, the standard $scope events behave a bit differently when you build your controllers using `controllerAs` syntax [See controllerAs Reference](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm).

```
function MainController($scope, $log) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.title = 'Some Title';
   vm.showPatientStepTwo = false;

   // does not work
   $scope.$watch('userType', function(newVal, oldVal){
        // do work
   });

   // works  
   $scope.$watch('vm.userType', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       // do work with newValue
   });

   // also works
   $scope.$watch(function() {
      return vm.userType;
   }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      vm.showPatientStepTwo = newValue === 'patient';
   });
}
```

**Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dth67cQJKarwt3NiE9yp**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Type of ad <b class="text-danger">*</b></label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="typeofAd" value="sell" ng-model="product.typeofAd">  I want to sell       
            <input type="radio" name="typeofAd" value="buy" ng-model="product.typeofAd"> I want to buy
          </div>
```

radio button this way works fine for me

refer link
https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms

Answer (score 0):

you need to add ng-model and ng-change event like below.

`<md-radio-group  ng-model="selectedVal" ng-change="showSelected()">`

and in your controller you can defined function as following.

`$scope.showSelected= function(){
                    console.log($scope.selectedVal);
                }`